# show only most related branch in a tree

Tags: jquery, tree

I've got a tree of categories:

CAT1

- CAT1child
- CAT2child

  - CAT1child of CAT2child

    - CAT1child of CAT1child of CAT2child
- CAT3child

Each category has a class of `cat-item`, current category (the one a person is viewing) has a class of `current-cat` and the parent of this current category is `current-cat-parent`. Children of each category are in an `<ul>` with a class `children`.

Now, when we go to a depth of, for example, three, and click CAT1child of CAT1child of CAT2child, then the same applies, it's parent (CAT1child of CAT2child) has a class of `current-cat-parent` and it's children are in an `<ul>` of a '`children`' class.

The problem is, as soon as we go deep into the tree then branches that are higher don't get a special category, because the parent of `current-cat-parent` does not get any class for being it's parent alone.

With such information in mind, how can I show only branches that lead to the current category and children of the current category (without children of their own)? I want our clients to be able to see what sub-categories are in the one they're viewing and what are the categories that lead to the category they're viewing.

**EDIT - My HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li class="cat-item">
      CAT1
      <ul class="children">
         <li class="cat-item">CAT1child</li>
         <li class="cat-item">CAT2child
            <ul class="children">
               <li class="cat-item current-cat-parent">CAT1child of CAT2child
                  <ul class="children">
                     <li class="cat-item current-cat">CAT1child of CAT1child of CAT2child</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</li>
```

Comment: I can't follow your question. Consider adding your markup.

Comment: I added my markup. What I want to achieve is to let the user see only categories that are parents for current-cat, but I don't want other children of those categories to be visible. Also, children of the current-cat should be visible, but children of those children shouldn't. So I want people to see only one step into the tree, but all steps out. With the exception, that all parent categories for current-cat shouldn't have their other children visible.